# Regrouping in a Django template after the first regroup

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a page that has a group of photos, categorized by event, then within the event, by date.
Currently, in my view, I am doing this:

`photos = Photo.objects.all().order_by('event')`

Then, in my template, I am doing this:

```
{% regroup photos by event as event_list %}
{% for event in event_list %}
    <h6 class="event-title">
        {{ event.grouper|safe }} ({{ event.grouper.date }})
     </h6>
     {% for photo in event.list %}
         <img data-src="{{ photo.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ event.grouper|safe }} ({{ event.grouper.date }})" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way I can group the photos once again by `photo.date_captured`?

Would it be better to do this in the view?

Comment: I think event in your for loop has a property event.list that you can once again regroup. Though I admit I have never tried this myself.

Comment: Yes, I did try to regroup on `event.list`, but I got a blank page with that attempt.